# Need assistance hooking up Sharp GP2Y0A41SK0F IR sensor

Tags: raspbian, sensor, python-3

So I have this...
Infrared Proximity Sensor Short Range - Sharp GP2Y0A41SK0F
& 1
MCP3002.
I have been scouring the web for hours, trying all code examples and I still get 0 as a reading no matter what. I am looking for any help.
I have 5v going into the sensor from the pi and back the ground, the MCP3002 is wired up correctly from what i presume.

```
________________
|MCP3002|  Pi  |
|   1   | CE0  |
|   2   |IR Out|
|   3   |  GND |
|   4   |  GND |
|   5   | 3.3v |
|   6   | SCLK |
|   7   | MISO |
|   8   | MOSI |
----------------
```

Comment: Please isolate issue using multimeter to confirm that GP2Y0A41SK0F Vo is actually changing between 0-Vcc.

Comment: We need as a minimum a photo of the connections and a listing of the software being used.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just tried some new code and its the only thing i get a reply with,

```
from __future__ import division

import spidev
from time import sleep

def bitstring(n):

    s = bin(n)[2:]

    return '0'*(8-len(s)) + s

def read(adc_channel=0, spi_channel=0):

    conn = spidev.SpiDev(0, spi_channel)

    conn.max_speed_hz = 1200000 # 1.2 MHz

    conn.mode = 0

    cmd = 192 #start bit + single ended

    if adc_channel:

        cmd += 32 #set the ODD/SIGN bit to select channel number

    reply_bytes = conn.xfer2([cmd, 0])

    reply_bitstring = ''.join(bitstring(n) for n in reply_bytes)

    reply = reply_bitstring[5:15]

    return int(reply, 2) / 2**10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print(read())
        sleep(1)
```

results in

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.5283203125
0.45703125
0.0
0.0
```

Without me moving or putting anything in front of the sensor.

[image]